# error using npx create-react-app : "authorization required to access package react"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

when I try to create a new project it shows me that error:

error An unexpected error occurred: "http://*some ip*/react: authorization required to access package react".

What can I do?

npm version : 7.21.0
node : 12.18.4

Comment: how are you using it like `npx create-react-app my-project` is this what you try to do

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you don't have some `.npmrc` file in the root folder or `$HOME/`. In my case I just removed it and it works.